# How to load external data with Flex Mobile?

Tags: web-services, apache-flex, mobile

I have a requirement to build a flex mobile app (iOS/Android) which is capable of downloading data from the web (product animations and associated data).

It needs to handle additional product lines if I add any and cache the data offline (in SQlite I guess).

I think web services is probably the answer but is it possible to load an external library such as SWF or SWC using this method?

Any help is much appreciated as always!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think web services is probably the answer but is it possible to load
>   an external library such as SWF or SWC using this method?

If you need to pass data to and from a Flex app then you can use [RemoteObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/remoting/mxml/RemoteObject.html) (AMF), [WebService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/mxml/WebService.html) (SOAP), or [HTTPService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/mxml/HTTPService.html) (REST).  My personal recommendation is to use RemoteObject/AMF whenever possible.

You can load another SWF at runtime using [SWFLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html).  I'm pretty sure that SWFLoader will not work on iOS as there are clauses in the iOS Developer agreement that you can have code that will interpret other code at runtime or something similar.

Comment: OK thanks, maybe I am complicating things too much in that case - any idea how long it would take for app updates to become available for iOS when I upload them?  this could be a cleaner solution as I could maintain the data with the update rather than load it externally?

Comment: If you're distributing through the iTunes app store; It depends how long it takes for Apple to approve them.  Once they are approved, I assume updates would happen pretty quickly.